# Heroku Ruby Buildpack Detection Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, buildpack

I'm attempting to deploy my Ruby on Rails application that is currently on branch "rails_app" (as shown below). I have successfully deployed it before, but it is now not working with additional changes. When I manually look for buildpacks by running "heroku buildpacks," it indicates the correct one is there. [When I try to reinstall the buildpack, it also says it is already there] When I attempt to push to heroku I receive the failure to detect set buildpath as shown below.

```
Dougs-MBP-2:Rails_Application Doug$ heroku buildpacks
app_name Buildpack URL
heroku/ruby
Dougs-MBP-2:Rails_Application Doug$ git branch
gh-pages
master
* rails_app
update
Dougs-MBP-2:Rails_Application Doug$ git push heroku rails_app:master
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 217.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 46), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to app_name.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/app_name.git
! [remote rejected] rails_app -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app_name.git'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting a custom buildpack: "https://codonbuildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz" but when I visit that link it says that no bucket with that name exists which means that heroku can't detect your custom buildpack and fails.

You can read more about how to specify custom buildpacks here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

The ruby buildpack that heroku uses is on this page: 
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby

Comment: My apologies, the correct link is https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz. The dash must have gotten lost when copying from my terminal. I have updated the original post.

Comment: Did you make sure that you have a Gemfile in your Git repo ? Did you add the buildpack using the heroku buildpack:set command ? Did you try clearing the set buildpacks of your app using "heroku buildpack:clear" ?

Comment: Yes to all of the above.